# OWASP ZAP share Context between environments and change base URI's addresses

Tags: zap

I'm new to ZAP tool so sorry in advance if question is stupid, but I cannot find answer on it so far...

I have to fix all the vulnerabilities in some application, so I installed ZAP proxy tool locally, then explored application manually, collected all the requests and ran 'Active scanner' against it. So far everything is good, but the problem is that application quite big and it's very difficult and time consuming to cover everything manually. Fortunately we have dedicated automation environment where I can setup ZAP proxy and let test's go and populate context (set of url's for test) for me

So now my task is somehow share context's between different environments with ability to change base addresses

e.g. I populated context on **somedomain**/myapp and want run ZAP tool against same application deployed locally, or in different server (e.g. **localhost**/myapp)

It would be very helpful if someone could share any info how to achieve that.

Thank you in advance,
Eugene

Comment: I got my question answered here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/zaproxy-users/share$20context/zaproxy-users/pOPDe5gvYrM/SMK8tElcAgAJ   there is no such functionality supported yet for this tool, however I can copy the 'Session' and than make changes in locale 'hosts' file

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can create new context and then add existing links to that context.

1. Craete a new context
2. Add existing link to the selected content (right click)

Check this link.
https://chrisdecairos.ca/intercepting-traffic-with-zaproxy/

Tiago

Comment: As I understood from ZAP terminology 'context' is kind of filter for URL's but not collected set of URL to be attacked. Folks from ZAP google group confirmed the same and given me that issue id (https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues/682) saying that required functionality is not yet supported.

Comment: But they also given me work around: share 'session' from staging and run it on locale env. with appropriate modifications in 'hosts' file.